# npm install @types/node error, @types not expanded

Tags: types, npm

When i exec "npm install @types/node", i get the following error:

```
[susl@bogon tmp]$ npm install @types/node
```

> npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:types/node Initialized empty Git repository in /home/susl/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-types-node-921b5735/ 
>   npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:types/node 
>   npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:types/node Permission denied (publickey). 
>   npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:types/node fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly 
>   npm ERR! addLocal Could not install types/node 
>   npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, stat 'types/node' 
>   npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at: 
>   npm ERR!     http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues 
>   npm ERR! or email it to: 
>   npm ERR!      
>   
>   npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-642.el6.x86_64 
>   npm ERR! command "/home/susl/bin/node" "/home/susl/bin/npm" "install" "@types/node" 
>   npm ERR! cwd /home/susl/tmp 
>   npm ERR! node -v v0.10.22 
>   npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.14 
>   npm ERR! path types/node 
>   npm ERR! code ENOENT 
>   npm ERR! errno 34 
>   npm ERR! 
>   npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in: 
>   npm ERR!     /home/susl/tmp/npm-debug.log 
>   npm ERR! not ok code 0

i guess that "@types" is not expanded, and the git repository git@github.com:types/node doesn't exist.
i don't know how @types works here, what should i do?

Comment: i resolve my problem after upgrading node to v 0.10.48.

Comment: did you solve this?